# Server side validation for the user Input

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I have a table in the web application from where the users can make orders. The table shows the Quantity that is available and we need to let users enter the quantity they need like below

[image]

when the Order button is clicked I want to validate if the user is entering the Quantity Required is greater than the Quantity Avail. Every time the Order button is clicked it calls the Controller to retrieve the data and check against the quantity. The view is like below

```
   @model JAXSurplusMouseApp.Models.CustomerInventoryCollectionDataModel

   @{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h3>Order Surplus Mouse</h3>

 <div class="col-md-9">
  <table class="table">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>
       Strain ID
     </th>
     <th>
       Strain Name
     </th>
     <th>
       Quantity Avail
     </th>
     <th>
       Room Number
     </th>
     <th>
       Quantity Required
     </th>
     <th></th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      @{var custID = Model.CustomerData; }
      @foreach (var item in Model.Inventorys)
      {
       <tr>
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StrainId)
        </td>
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StrainName)
        </td>
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuantityAvailable)
        </td>
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoomNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
         <form method="post"
               asp-controller="Inventories"
               asp-action="OrderItem">
         <row>
           <column>
             <input type="text" id="quantityReq" name="quantityReq" value=@item.QuantityReq size="4" />
             <input type="hidden" id="customerID" name="customerID" value="@custID.CustomerId" />
             <input type="hidden" id="invetoryID" name="invetoryID" value="@item.InventoryId" />
             <button type="submit" style="border: none; background-color: transparent; color: #1a0dab "><u>Order</u></button>
          </column>
        </row>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
 }
 </tbody>
</table>
 @{
    var prevDisabled = !Model.Inventorys.HasPreviousPage ? "disabled" : "";
    var nextDisabled = !Model.Inventorys.HasNextPage ? "disabled" : "";
   }
   <a asp-action="Index"
      asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]"
      asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.Inventorys.PageIndex - 1)"
      asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
      class="btn btn-default @prevDisabled"> Previous </a>
    <a asp-action="Index"
       asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]"
       asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.Inventorys.PageIndex + 1)"
       asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
       class="btn btn-default @nextDisabled"> Next </a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

And Controller action I am calling when clicking on the button is

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OrderItem(int? customerID, int? invetoryID, int quantityReq)
{
    if (customerID == null || invetoryID == null || quantityReq == 0)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    Customer custData = await _context.Customers.FindAsync(customerID);
    var intData = await _context.Inventories.FindAsync(invetoryID);

        if (quantityReq <= intData.QuantityAvailable)
        {
            MouseOrder mo = new MouseOrder();
            mo.CustomerId = (int)customerID;
            mo.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;
            mo.SamaccountName = "dvella";
            _context.Add(mo);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            InventoryOrder io = new InventoryOrder();
            io.OrderId = mo.MouseOrderId;
            io.OrderQuantity = quantityReq;
            io.InventoryId = (int)invetoryID;
            _context.Add(io);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            intData.QuantityAvailable = intData.QuantityAvailable - quantityReq;
            _context.Update(intData);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();                
        }

        else if (quantityReq > intData.QuantityAvailable){
        
             
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Inventories", new { id = customerID });
    }
```

Get action in the Controller is like below

```
    // GET: Inventories
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? id, string sortOrder, string searchString,
                                            int? pageNumber, string currentFilter)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        ViewData["StockParam"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "st_desc" : "";
        ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;
        ViewData["CurrentSort"] = sortOrder;

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            pageNumber = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        var inventories_data = from s in _context.Inventories
                               where s.QuantityAvailable >0
                            select s;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            inventories_data = inventories_data.Where(s => s.StrainCode.Contains(searchString));
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "st_desc":
                inventories_data = inventories_data.OrderByDescending(s => s.StrainCode);
                break;
            default:
                inventories_data = inventories_data.OrderBy(s => s.StrainCode);
                break;
        }
        int pageSize = 15;

        Customer custData = await _context.Customers.FindAsync(id);
        var inventories = await PaginatedList<Inventory>.CreateAsync(inventories_data.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize);
        var model = new CustomerInventoryCollectionDataModel
        {
            CustomerData = custData,
            Inventorys = inventories
        };
        return View(model);

    }
```

Model Class is like

```
public class CustomerInventoryCollectionDataModel
    {
        public Customer CustomerData { get; set; }
        public PaginatedList<Inventory> Inventorys { get; set; }
    }
```

Where the Inventory Class is like

```
public partial class Inventory
{
    public string StrainId { get; set; }
    public string StrainName { get; set; }
    public int QuantityAvailable { get; set; }
    public string RoomNumber { get; set; }
    public int InventoryId { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int? QuantityReq { get; set; }
}
```

I am developing a web application for the first time using the .NET Core with EF and kind of stuck with this. Please Suggest me how can I handle the validation here. I am here not so particular where the validation message should be shown but a way to notify the users to enter the correct number. I appreciate all the help

****EDIT ****

I see the error like
[image]

When I enter less or more than the the Quantity Available it is not doing anything, in the devtools I see the error like the screenshot

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name`

Before pressing the Buy Now button the URL is like `https://localhost:44330/Inventories/Index/460` Any after I pressed the `https://localhost:44330/Inventories/Index/460#`

I am not able to troubleshoot more , kind of stuck here

Comment: It is hard to tell what  is going on since you posted only a part of view. Can you show a get action and full view including model pls?

Comment: @Serge I added all the details, please let me know if I am missing something. I am kind of stuck here. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: @Serge The order creation and all works.. Its just when user enters the quantityReq > intData.QuantityAvailable I am not sure how to show validation errrors

Comment: @Serge I entered all the code ,can you please help me with this when you get a chance.  I am kind of stuck

Comment: Since your application is going to use paging it makes things much more complicated. You will have to use  some javascript and ajax for validation. Are you ready for this or you prefer to remove paging from your project?

Comment: @Serge Pagination is pretty important as we have so many of records, but can you please guide me how I can deal with javascript and ajax for validation

Comment: @Serge if I remove the Pagination, does the validation going to be straight forward?

Comment: The problem is to show what record has the validation error. If you  had all records on one page, you could use submit and return all records back. But since you have several pages it will be a big problem to return the records back in the same order and  put  a not valid record is in the same place.  It is much easier to mark invalid record using javascript in this case. This way everything remains as it was.

Comment: Without javascript you  will have to double click record or click a link to select the record that should be changed. After this  will be returned view with only this record details. After changing field or fields,  you can submit the record back. If it is ok it will return the index view, if not , the same view with one record will return back with error message.

Comment: @Serge So Ideally I need to go to the Record detail page and add them to the order and show the validation in the details instead of the index().

Comment: @Serge Do you think I can have a toast or some kind of popup that can be shown in the Index() page when the Validation fails..

Comment: No, popup would be no good at all since you have a table with many rows. There are two ways - you press buy button and  show  you show the detail view with only one record and put quantiy there , or you put quantity on main page and after submitting it will validate and return  error if it is .  Nobody uses pop ups now, since every browser has pop-ups blokers.

Comment: I will create ajax code for you , but it will take some time, since it needs to be tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. Since it is using ajax I removed a form and a submit button

```
 @model JAXSurplusMouseApp.Models.CustomerInventoryCollectionDataModel

   @{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h3>Order Surplus Mouse</h3>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="padding-right:1em">
                Strain ID
            </th>
            <th style="padding-right:1em">
                Strain Name
            </th>
            <th style="padding-right:1em">
                Room
            </th>
            <th style="padding-right:1em">
                Quantity Avail
            </th>

            <th>
                Quantity Required
            </th>
    <tbody>

        @foreach(var item in Model.Inventorys)
        {
        <tr>
            <td />
            <td />
            <td />
            <td />
            <td style="padding-right:1em">
                <input type="text" class="text-danger float-right" style="border:none;font-size: smaller" id="@("errorMessage"+@item.InventoryId)" readonly />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="padding-left:2em">
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StrainId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StrainName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoomNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuantityAvailable)
            </td>

            <td>
                <row>
                    <column>
                        <input type="text" style="text-align:right;padding-right:1em" id="@("quantityReq"+@item.InventoryId)" name="quantityReq" value="@item.QuantityReq" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </column>
                    <column>
                        <input type="hidden" id="@("customer"+@item.InventoryId)" name="customerID" value="@Model.CustomerData.Id" />
                        <input type="hidden" id="@("inventory"+@item.InventoryId)" name="invetoryID" value="@item.InventoryId" />
                        <a href="#" class="buyNow" data-id="@item.InventoryId"> Buy now</a>
                </row>
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@section Scripts {

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on("click", ".buyNow", (function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();

                 var id=$(this).data("id");
               
              

                onBuyNow(id);

            }));

            function onBuyNow(id) {

                $("#errorMessage" + id).val("");

                var quantityReq = $("#quantityReq"+id).val();
                var customerId = $("#customer"+id).val();
                var data = {
                    customerId: customerId,
                    quantityReq: quantityReq,
                    inventoryId: id
                };

       

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("OrderItem", "Inventories")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (result) {
                    if (result.status !== "Ok") {
                            $("#errorMessage" + result.inventoryId).val("available only " + result.available);
                    }
                    else {
                            var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Inventories")';
                            url=url++"?id="+customerId;
                            alert("url: " + url);
                            window.location.href = url;
                        };
                    error: function (error) {
                     alert("error");
                    }
                });
                };
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

action

```
public async Task<ActionResult> OrderItem(int? customerID, int? inventoryID, int quantityReq)
{
    if (customerID == null || invetoryID == null || quantityReq == 0)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    Customer custData = await _context.Customers.FindAsync(customerID);
    var intData = await _context.Inventories.FindAsync(inventoryID);

        if (quantityReq <= intData.QuantityAvailable)
        {
           ... your code                
        }
        else if (quantityReq > intData.QuantityAvailable){
            return Ok( new { status = "NotAvailable",  inventoryId=inventoryId, available = intData.QuantityAvailable} );
        }
        return Ok(new { status="Ok" } );
}
```

and the bottom of a body section of your layout  should have

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: I cant thank you enough for taking time in getting this.. I am trying to understand how the call works , I have enabled breakpoints on the newly added scripts of Index page I am seeing an issue the ` $.ajax({ url: '@Url.Action("OrderItem", "Inventories")',` function gets called on the Inedx page load and nothing happens when the Buy now link is clicked.. I see in the browser like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name`. Do you think I a missing something, is it supposed to call the `$.ajax({url: '@Url.Action("OrderItem", "Inventories")',` on page load

Comment: You have to ihstalll javascript and jquery in your project. You can use libman for this. Google this name. And check developer tools => console in your browser for an error, if  button click is still not  working

Comment: I tried my best but still stuck with the same issue `Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name` I updated the question with the details of what I am seeing

Comment: I tried to add break point on my controller to see the action `OrderItem` is called from the Buy Now button but looks like the action is not called at all

Comment: @user81642 Since you never worked with javascript before, you have to go slow, one step in a time. Check my code. I added 2 alerts. Add them to your code too and let me know how things are going on.

Comment: I added the alert statements when I click Buy Now still I dont see any alert coming up.. Just seeing `Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name` on the Devtools

Comment: @user81642 I expedcted it. Go to javascript code  in Visual studio and check the  syntax very well. Especially check brakets, and functions names.  There are just syntax erroe there. there is a checkmark at the bottom of javascrit  code screen. This checkmark should be green.

Comment: When the view is loaded for the first time only I am seeing this `Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name` exception even before pressing the Buy Now

Comment: Thanks a ton that really really helped.. Again I cant thank you more

Comment: @user81642 You are very welcome. Have you found  a bug?

Comment: @user81642 I am glad for you

Comment: I was earlier doing the NotFound() to handle if the input parameters are null when I was using the `Task<IActionResult>` now since I am changing it to `Task<JsonResult>` it will not work correct

Comment: @user81642 I fixed to the action result. Pls try new code.

Comment: I tried to follow the same logic as you explained here in my another page but looks like I am missing something https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69811808/button-to-update-the-order-quantity-is-not-working-as-expected Can you please help me with it

Comment: @user81642 I am sorry but I tested this code many times in my Visual Studio 2019 and everything was  working properly. I always test my answers before posting

Comment: @user81642 I checked your another question.  I  already told you before that you have to decide which way to go : you use  a form and sumbit button,  or ajax but  no form and no submit button.  You selected something in the middle  and you have a lot of bug in your code.

Comment: No I didnt mean to say your code is not working.. It works perfect, I am so sorry. I tried to follow the same in the other page but kind of stuck.

Comment: I initially was just using the form and couldnt get the user input to the controller so I  changed to call the ajax on the button click.. I see the data is being passed to the controller action. Can you please let me know what I should be changing