# Button to Update the Order Quantity is not working as expected

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to have a button that allows the users to update the Quantity of the items they ordered. When the users tries to update the Quantity that is more than what is available I need to do nothing and show an error message saying something like Entered Quantity is more than what is available and shouldn't update anything in the DB

The View

```
      <form asp-action="EditItem">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
         ..............
                       <!--<input type="text" class="text-danger float-right" style="border:none;font-size: smaller" id="@("errorMessage")"" readonly /> -->
                <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="OrderQuantity" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="OrderQuantity" id="txt" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="OrderQuantity" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="orderId" name="orderId" value="@Model.OrderId" />
            <input type="hidden" id="inventoryorderId" name="inventoryorderId" value="@Model.InventoryOrderId" />
            <input type="hidden" id="inventoryId" name="inventoryId" value="@Model.InventoryId" />
            <button id="button">Update</button>
        </form>
       </div>
     </div>

@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#button").click(function () {
        var orderedQuantity = $("#txt").val();
        var orderId = $("#orderId").val();
        var inventoryorderId = $("#inventoryorderId").val();
        var inventoryId = $("#inventoryId").val();

        var data = {
            orderId: orderId,
            inventoryorderId: inventoryorderId,
            inventoryId: inventoryId,
            orderedQuantity: orderedQuantity
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("EditItem", "Orders")',
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result !== "") {
                    if (result.available == "NotAvailable")
                        $("#errorMessage").val("Enter a valid Quantity");
                }
                else if (result == "")  {
                    var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Orders")';
                    window.location.href = url + "?custEmail=xy@rrr.org";
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    }
```

Controller Action

```
    public async Task<JsonResult> EditItem(int? orderId, int? inventoryorderId, int? inventoryId, int? orderedQuantity)
    {
        var inventoryOrder = await _context.InventoryOrders
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(io => io.InventoryOrderId == inventoryorderId);
        int curentOrdQuantity = inventoryOrder.OrderQuantity;
        inventoryOrder.OrderQuantity = (int)orderedQuantity;
        _context.SaveChanges();

        var intData = await _context.Inventories.FindAsync(inventoryId);
        int availQty = intData.QuantityAvailable;
        if ((int)orderedQuantity > curentOrdQuantity)
        {
            if (availQty < ((int)orderedQuantity - curentOrdQuantity))
            {
                return Json(new { status = "NotAvailable", available = intData.QuantityAvailable });
            }
            else
            {
                //Updating the Order
                inventoryOrder.OrderQuantity = (int)orderedQuantity;
                _context.Update(inventoryOrder);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                //Updating Inventory
                intData.QuantityAvailable = intData.QuantityAvailable - ((int)orderedQuantity - curentOrdQuantity);
                _context.Update(intData);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();                    
            }
        }
        else if ((int)orderedQuantity < curentOrdQuantity)
        {
            //Updating the Order
            inventoryOrder.OrderQuantity = (int)orderedQuantity;
            _context.Update(inventoryOrder);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            //Updating Inventory
            intData.QuantityAvailable = intData.QuantityAvailable + (curentOrdQuantity - (int)orderedQuantity);
            _context.Update(intData);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();                
        }
        return Json("");
    }
```

There are two issue

1. When the Quantity entered is more I am trying `return Json(new { status = "NotAvailable", available = intData.QuantityAvailable });` but still the OrderQuantity in the database got updated to the new value that was entered. Even though I am not updating the Order in the code it got updated to newly entered value. How can I restore it to old value and not change what was entered
2. when the Quantity is lesser than the QuantityAvailable I am updating both the inventory and the order and returning `return Json("");` I was hoping to navigate back to the Index page

   ```
          else if (result == "")  {
                var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Orders")';
                window.location.href = url + "?custEmail=xy@rrr.org";
            }
   ```

but nothing happens it just stays in the smae page. Can anyone please help what I am missing here

***EDIT***
The first issue is reolved but still I am not able to get the success() work on the ajax
I tried to add alert in the success but my alert is not showing up

```
     success: function (result) {
       alert(result);
                if (result !== "") {
                    if (result.available == "NotAvailable")
                        $("#errorMessage").val("Enter a valid Quantity");
                }
                else if (result == "")  {
```

Model Class

```
public class Order
{
    public int CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId  { get; set; }
    public int InventoryId { get; set; }
    public int InventoryOrderId { get; set; }
    public string StrainId { get; set; }
    public string StrainName { get; set; }
    public string StrainCode { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }
    public string Genotype { get; set; }
    public int QuantityAvailable { get; set; }
    public int OrderQuantity { get; set; }
    public string RoomNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First Issue

You always update the DB, the first rows of your method get the InventoryOrderand update the row, I commented out the code

```cs
public async Task<JsonResult> EditItem(int? orderId, int? inventoryorderId, int? inventoryId, int? orderedQuantity)
    {
        var inventoryOrder = await _context.InventoryOrders
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(io => io.InventoryOrderId == inventoryorderId); // Get the InventoryOrder
        int curentOrdQuantity = inventoryOrder.OrderQuantity; // Save the currentOrdQUantity
        inventoryOrder.OrderQuantity = (int)orderedQuantity; // UPDATE the OrderQuantity
        _context.SaveChanges(); // <- Persist to DB
```

### Second Issue

I suggest you to add a `console.log(result);` after the `success: function (result) {`

### Consideration

- With the `Nullable` you can use the `.Value` for accessing the value i.e. `orderId.Value` instead of `(int)orderId`.
- Since you pass *nullable* values consider checking if are null before casting or reading the value

Comment: I tried to add alert inside `success: function (result) {
       alert(result);` but nothing is showing up when the button is clicked.. Do you think I am missing something

Comment: I tried even having the `console.log(result);` I think the code is not hitting there at all. Can you please tell me what is that I am missing here

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint on CSharp code and see if the last `return Json("")` is hit. Another consideration is: when the `orderedQuantity == curentOrdQuantity` what happened?

Comment: Have you added another question for the [second issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69811808/button-to-update-the-order-quantity-is-not-working-as-expected/69813058?noredirect=1#comment123406700_69813058)? I see from the other question that you have changed the CSharp code, update this question and delete the other.

Comment: I deleted the other question. The `return Json("")` is getting hit though but nothing I am seeing again on the console/alert

Comment: Try to return `Ok()` instead of `Json("")`

Comment: Tried that as well, seeing the same behavior

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238842/discussion-between-max-and-user4912134).

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you don't need ajax for this

view

```
@model CustomerInventoryModel

form asp-controller="Orders" asp-action="EditItem" method="post">

...... other use controls

    <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Inventory.QuantityAvailable" class="control-label" readonly></label>
                <input asp-for="Inventory.QuantityAvailable "  class="form-control" />
       </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Inventory.QuantityReq" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Inventory.QuantityReq" class="form-control" />
        <input value="@Model.Inventory.ErrorMessage" class="form-control text-danger float-right" style="border:none;font-size: smaller" />
    </div>
    
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="CustomerId" value="@Model.CustomerId" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Inventory.InventoryId" value="@Model.Inventory.InventoryId" />
    <div>
        <button id="buyNow" type="submit">  Buy now </button>
    </div>

</form>
```

add ErrorMessage property to Inventory class

```
public partial class Inventory
{
    public int InventoryId { get; set; }
   ......
   
     [NotMapped]
    public string ErrorMessage{ get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int? QuantityReq { get; set; }
}
```

and create a detail view model

```
public class CustomerInventoryModel
{
        public  int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public Inventory Inventory { get; set; }
}
```

action

```
public async Task<ActionResult> OrderItem(CustomerInventoryModel model)
{
    
    Customer custData = await _context.Customers.FindAsync(model.CustomerID);
    var intData = await _context.Inventories.FindAsync(model.Inventory.InventoryID);

        if (model.Inventory.QuantityReq <= intData.QuantityAvailable)
        {
           ... your code  

          return Redirect("Index", new {id=model.CustomerId} );             
        }
       
          model.ErrorMessage("not enough")
         return View(model);
}
```

Comment: This uses a different model called order. I added the model class that is used for the view, the reason for choosing the ajax was to capture user entered value in the input box and compare it against DB

Comment: @user4912134 It is just my humble opinion.